# Changing form action URL dynamically using AJAX for load balancing?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, upload, load-balancing

I want to do some load balancing for a file server, basically I want to upload files on different servers based on which ever server has the minimum load and this has to be done dynamically after user presses the submit button because I also need to take into account the input file extension, so to do that I'm thinking when a user will click on the submit button to upload a file, an AJAX query will be made to a URL which will return the final destination server after doing some algorithmic analysis and the results of this AJAX query will then change the action field of the input form and then the file will be uploaded to that server. So what I want to know if this is a good approach? or if there's a better way?

Comment: What's wrong with just using `haproxy` to distribute the load?

Comment: Instead of trying to do this client-side, why not just route the request server-side?